# How to add content to specific column in csv using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I'm not good at javascript I've tried to search on stackoverflow.com but unable to find any help I'm trying to create CSV where I want to add content below relevant column heading/index, where the column heading/index is array key and column content is value, below is code but it is showing data only in two columns:

```
 function downloadCSV(csvStr) {
  CSV = ConvertToCSV(csvStr);
  var uri = [
  [
    'application.csv','data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV)
  ]];
  downloadAll(uri)
}
function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
   var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

   let str = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   var line = '';
   for (var index in array[i]) {
       if (line != '') line += ''
       line +=  `${index} ,` 
       line +=  `${array[i][index]}` 
      }
     str += line + '\n';
   }
   return str;
 }
```

And below is the array data I have where I want to use First, Street Address as the column heading

```
0: {First: 'asdkjf,\n', Street Address: 'lasdkfj ,\n', City: 
   'alsdf,\n', State: 'Alaska,\n', ZIP / Postal Code: 'asl;dfj,\n', …}
1: {First: 'asdkjf,\n', Street Address: 'lasdkfj ,\n', City: 'alsdf,\n', State: 'Alaska,\n', ZIP / Postal Code: 'asl;dfj,\n', …}
```

This is how I'm getting the result
[image]

Comment: I would recommend papaparse for dealing with csv

Comment: Because data might contain `"` or `,` or `\n` etc. Anyway this is wrong `if (line != '') line += ''`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example. This assumes you are receiving JSON Data format.

```js
var myDataArray = [{
  "First": "asdkjf",
  "Street Address": "lasdkfj",
  "City": "alsdf",
  "State": "Alaska",
  "ZIP / Postal Code": "asl;dfj"
}, {
  "First": "asdkjf",
  "Street Address": "lasdkfj",
  "City": "alsdf",
  "State": "Alaska",
  "ZIP / Postal Code": "asl;dfj"
}];

function convertToCSV(jsonData) {
  var rows = [];
  jsonData.forEach(function(obj, i) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach(function(key, j) {
      rows.push(['"' + key + '"', '"' + obj[key] + '"'].join(","));
    });
    rows.push('\r\n');
  });
  return rows.join("\r\n");
}

console.log(convertToCSV(myDataArray));
```

You can make use of many of the Array tools. This helps create the comma separation. `arr.join(",")` will result in a String of each element of the array, joined by a `,`.

This results in the following:

```
"First","asdkjf"\r\n
"Street Address","lasdkfj"\r\n
"City","alsdf"\r\n
"State","Alaska"\r\n
"ZIP / Postal Code","asl;dfj"\r\n
\r\n
"First","asdkjf"\r\n
"Street Address","lasdkfj"\r\n
"City","alsdf"\r\n
"State","Alaska"\r\b
"ZIP / Postal Code","asl;dfj"\r\n
\r\n
```

CSV Format is generally:

```
Cell1,Cell2,Cell3\r\n
Cell4,Cell5,Cell6\r\n
```

Where each line is terminated with a Carriage Return (`\r`) and New Line (`\n`) character at the End of Line. Some Operating systems do not use the Carriage Return. If this is a Windows format, you will want to use both. More complex CSV content may need to quoted,  enclosed within double-quote characters.

See More:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values
- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#page-1

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the answer given by @Twisty because it was again creating only two columns where column one was heading (array key) and two was content (array value) what I needed was to add all headings (array keys) to top row and content (array value) to relevant box.
I know it's less efficient because I used three loops but it was the only choice to me so far!

Here is the code below:

```
function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
  var jsonData = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
  var rows = [];
  let inc   = 1;
  jsonData.forEach(function(obj, i) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let keyInc  = 1;
    if (inc === 1) {
      keys.forEach(function(key, j) {
        if (keyInc === 1) {
          rows.push([',"' + key + '"'].join(","));
        } else {
          rows.push(['"' + key + '"'].join(","));
        }
        keyInc++
      });
      rows.push('\n\n');
    }
    keys.forEach(function(key, j) {
      if (obj[key].includes('"')) {
        let doubleQuoteValue = obj[key].replaceAll('"', '');
        rows.push(['"' + doubleQuoteValue + '"'].join(","));
        console.log('double quote',doubleQuoteValue);
      } else {
        rows.push(['"' + obj[key] + '"'].join(","));
      }
      console.log(obj[key]);
  
      keyInc++
    });
    inc++;
    rows.push('\n');
  });
  return rows;
}
```